# CSS3 Animations from Path. How to implement it?

Tags: css, animation, svg, path, adobe-illustrator

I'm using CSS animations and jQuery to move cars in a crossroad to simulate a driving license quiz.

Sample image:
http://i39.tinypic.com/2gv6ma0.jpg

Each car has properties and an animation like this for example: red car turning left.

```
@-webkit-keyframes "move-a" {
 20% {
   left: 155px;
   top: 250px;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-75deg);
   transform: rotate(-75deg);   
 }
 40% {
   left: 148px;
   top: 210px;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-100deg);
   transform: rotate(-100deg);
 }
 60% {
   left: 135px;
   top: 170px;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-120deg);
   transform: rotate(-120deg);
 }
 80% {
   left: 90px;
   top: 150px;   
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
   transform: rotate(-180deg);
 }
 100% {
   left: 10px;
   top: 145px;   
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
   transform: rotate(-180deg);
 }
```

I have to do 40 different animated crossroads with 3-4-5 cars each and make every car's animation by this way is a suicide.

**I know that it's possible to draw the path on Adobe Illustrator, export it as SVG and convert it in CSS3 animation.**

*The questions are:*

How can I obtain a simple CSS code like mine (with more keyframes)?

How can I do this?

How can I implement this method?

What's the better way/tool to do this?

Comment: I'd go for something based around SVG/SMIL animateMotion e.g. http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/images/animate/animMotion01.svg

Comment: You're trying to use CSS for something it wasn't designed to do, use an alternative animation technology proposed in answers.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do this by applying two animation classes to two nested divs - one which handless the X motion and one which handles the Y motion, and adjusting the cubic bezier easing for each animation until you get the motion that you want.

It's far easier to use [SVG SMIL animation and directly animate your content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animateMotion). Or use snap or raphael svg animation libs.